# Best way to make a simple orderable playlist in django

Tags: jquery, django, json, orm, playlist

simple django orm question:

I've got a pretty classic example of a playlist and track models:

```
class Track(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    mp3 =  models.FileField(upload_to="track/")

class Playlist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

class PlaylistTrack(models.Model):
    playlist = models.ForeignKey('track.Playlist')
    track =    models.ForeignKey('track.Track')
    position = models.IntegerField() #Here's the crux of the problem
```

Is this the best way of making an orderable playlist?

I doubt it, but if so, how do I get an ordered `QuerySet`? (I will be serialising to json, so a `QuerySet` is prefered, but if you have a different, simple, way of making json I'd love to hear it!)

Here's what I have so far:

```
playlist = Track.objects.filter(playlisttrack__playlist__exact=1)
```

But this doesn't preserve ordering, according to `PlaylistTrack.position` field...

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you notice that your *PlaylistTrack* model is nothing more than a Many-2-Many intermediate table, then things will become more obvious (check [this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany)):

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    tracks = models.ManyToManyField('Track', through='PlaylistTrack')

class PlaylistTrack(models.Model):
    playlist = models.ForeignKey('track.Playlist')
    track =    models.ForeignKey('track.Track')
    position = models.IntegerField() #Here's the crux of the problem

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['position']
```

Now you can just do:

```
my_playlist.tracks.all()
```

Comment: +1 to this. It always makes things easier to start with clean output from your data source!

Comment: I've got full control of data, so I'll go with this slight change to my data - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If its order that you're worried about just add an `order_by` clause to the end of your query.

```
playlist = Track.objects.filter(playlisttrack__playlist__exact=1).order_by('+playlisttrack__position')
```

To dump the result set to json simply:

```
json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
json_serializer.serialize(playlist, ensure_ascii=False, stream=response)
```

Comment: Are you sure that you can simplejson.dump a model? I'm trying it on a complex model and I'm getting a "cannot serialise to JSON" error. Maybe that's because I'm trying it on a complex model here at work? I'll try on my simple playlist when I get home...

Comment: I imagine it will be serializable with `django.core.serializers` ?

Comment: Hrm it looks like you may not be able to do it directly with `simplejson`. I've updated my answer.