# Referntial objects gets deleted when deleting a foreign key in django model

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I am making an audio player in django. When I delete the songs in a playlist, the song gets deleted even from the Song database. I would like to delete the song only from a playlist and not from the song database. But if a song gets deleted from song database, all its instances in playlists should also get deleted.

models.py

```
class Song(models.Model):
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='/',default = "null")
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['song_title']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title

class Playlist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    songs = models.ManyToManyField(Song)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def deleteplaylistsong(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        song = (request.POST['song'])
        playlist = request.POST['playlist']
        s = Song.objects.get(song_title=song)
        p = Playlist.objects.get(name=playlist)
        p.songs.remove(s)
        return HttpResponse("success")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. According to [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.remove) referential objects are not getting deleted when you do `obj.fkfield.remove(ref_obj)`. There must be some additional python code (`m2m_changed` signals maybe) that is not posted here and is creating some side effects.
2. As soon as you remove `Song` object, all references to this item in `Playlist` objects will be automatically removed.

P.S. This view and models sound like a perfect case for unittests.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the PlaylistTrack model altogether; there's no need for it. In your view do:

```
p.songs.remove(s)
```

Comment: Remove it as well. If you're not doing anything special in the through model, there's no point having one.

Comment: The idea was taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799378/best-way-to-make-a-simple-orderable-playlist-in-django. Is there any way to do that with same schema?

Comment: And   even after changing the schema as you mentioned, the same happens.

Comment: Do *what*? That question was explicitly adding ordering on the through table; you're not doing that. However, there is no way that the code you have posted is itself deleting the Song.